# VBA: How to describe row with specific string

Tags: excel, vba, loops, sum

Hi I'm trying to create a loop that identifies a specific string in column "B", and SUMs up the values in column "D" of the same row. So far I've been able to identify the "cash" but now I don't know how to describe column "D" of the SAME row and sum it up. Please help!

Below is what I've got so far for this loop.

```
Dim CD As Long
Dim text As String
Dim Z As Long

CD = 0

For Z = 1 To Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    text = Range("B" & Z).Value
    If Left(text, 4) = "Cash" Then
        Sum....
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following the code you have provided, this would be what you are looking for:

```
Sub calculateSum()

    Dim CD As Long
    Dim text As String
    Dim Z As Long

    'Create a variable to store the sum and set its value to 0.
    Dim sum As Double 
    sum = 0

    CD = 0

    For Z = 1 To Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    text = Range("B" & Z).Value
        If Left(text, 4) = "Cash" Then
            'Increase the sum by the value stored in column D on the same row.
            sum = sum + Range("D" & Z).Value
        End If
    Next Z

    'Display the final result (sum).
    MsgBox "Sum: " & sum

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

You could certainly do something like:

```
For Z = 1 To Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    text = cells(Z,2).Value
    If Left(text, 4) = "Cash" Then
         Sum.... Zum = Zum + cells(Z,4).value
```

However, the computation could be done with a simple worksheet formula

```
=SUMIF(B:B,"cash*",D:D)
```

Comment: Or in VBA via `Application.SumIf([B:B], "cash*", [D:D])` if he need the number just in VBA (to do it in ws makes more sense to me)

Comment: Thank you for your help! Working well.